# Subtract row from all rows with same identifier using R

Tags: r, group-by, dplyr

I am fairly new to R and programming/scripting in general (and thus also SO). So forgive me, if the question is not in perfect style. I might also lack some of the "vocabulary" of more advanced R-people :)

What I want to do is, subtract a value in a row of a dataframe from all other data in a in the data frame which share a common identifier.
I found the built-in Theoph dataset in R, with which I can explain further what I want to do (this does not make any biological sense for this particular dataset, but is easier then posting my actual data).

I want to subtract the conc value which belongs to the time 0.00 from all other conc values. And this should be done for each subject individually. I first tried this by pulling out the data of only one of the subjects. This works using the code below:

```
# using a part (only one subject) of the built-in Theoph dataset
test2 <- subset(Theoph, Theoph$Subject=="1") 
test2 <- mutate(test2, diffconc = conc - subset(test2$conc, test2$Time==0.00))
```

Now I would like to do the same for all the subjects. I tried that using the group_by function of dplyr and grouped it by Subject and then combining this with mutate(). See Below:

```
# trying it with the whole built-in Theoph dataset (for every subject individually) 
Theoph %>%   group_by(Subject) %>%   mutate(diffconc = conc - subset(Theoph$conc, Theoph$Time==0.00)) -> test3
```

But this does not work as I expected. I am not sure how to correctly index, that it is done subject by subject.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in this mutate statement:

```
Theoph %>%   
group_by(Subject) %>%   
mutate(diffconc = conc - subset(Theoph$conc, Theoph$Time==0.00))
```

your `subset` operates on the entire `Theoph` dataframe, bypassing your `group_by` statement: it searches for Time==0 in the entire dataframe, not just within each Subject, so it finds all instances of Time==0.

This is why it works when you extract a single Subject (there is exactly one instance of Time==0), but not when you use the same code following `group_by`.

The following would work, assuming that there is always exactly one Time == 0 for each Subject:

```
Theoph %>%
group_by(Subject) %>%   
mutate(diffconc = conc - conc[Time==0])
```

Comment: THanks for the answer and the explanation, why my idea did not work.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly, you could try:

```
transmute(
  left_join(Theoph,
          rename(
            select(
              filter(Theoph,Time==0.00),
              Subject,conc),
            conc0=conc),
          by="Subject"),
  Subject,Wt,Dose,Time,conc,diffconc=conc-conc0)
```

Comment: Thanks for that solution. Although I chose the solution of @Janna Maas (because it was much easier to implement on my data set), it would be awesome if you could elaborate a bit, what your code actually does. This might help me a bit in the future.